# Adding a new Echosign template in Salesforce

Tags: apex

There is a requirement in which I have to create a new Echosign template in salesforce with fields' reference from different objects. I looked for that on web but couldn't find anything. Can you help please?

Comment: You may want to post this on the Adobe community site for [Salesforce Integration questions](https://forums.adobe.com/community/document-cloud-esign-services/salesforce_integration?view=overview).

Answer (score 2):

In Salesforce, click on 'EchoSign Admin' object tab.  Then click on 'Resources' and you will find 5 different links for documentation, one of which is 'EchoSign for Salesforce Customization and Installation Guide."  You should be able to setup the agreement template using that.

As for the agreement template:
Create a new agreement template by clicking on the agreement templates tab and 'New.'  Your master object type will be the object that will be referenced for this agreement template.  Once you've entered all information and save the template, scroll to the section that says 'Map Data into Agreement Fields.'  This is the section that will allow you to map data from Salesforce objects into your agreement fields.

Click on 'New Map Data into Agreement Field' then select 'Select Master Object Field' from the picklist and click Next.  Select the source field from Master Object and the target agreement field and click Save.

You can also setup Merge Mappings from multiple objects by clicking on the EchoSign Merge Mapping Tab.  This will allow you to quickly map data from Salesforce into the agreement fields.  The Data Mapping tab will allow you to map data from a signed agreement into Salesforce.

I hope this helps.